# import only \mathvisiblespace from stix without importing the whole stix

Tags: math-mode, fonts, stix

Continuing [How to use only selected math symbols of the STIX fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254618/how-to-use-only-selected-math-symbols-of-the-stix-fonts), how to import the normal symbol `\mathvisiblespace` from stix (or from some other suitable font)? The following attempt gives a different symbol. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\@noaccents}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsstix}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathvisiblespace}{0}{symbolsstix}{"B6}
\begin{document}
\(\{0,1,\mathvisiblespace\}\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsstix}{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsstix}{bold}{LS1}{stixscr}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathvisiblespace}{0}{symbolsstix}{"B6}

\begin{document}

\(\{0,1,\mathvisiblespace\}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need bold math, a simpler strategy will do as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathvisiblespace}{%
  \mathord{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}\symbol{"B6}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\(\{0,1,\mathvisiblespace\}\)

\end{document}
```

For a command that obeys `\boldmath`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236903/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pdftexcmds}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathvisiblespace}{%
  \mathord{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stixscr}{\normalorbold}{n}\symbol{"B6}}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\normalorbold}{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\math@version}{bold}=\z@\bfdefault\else\mddefault\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(\{0,1,\mathvisiblespace\}\)

{\boldmath\(\{0,1,\mathvisiblespace\}\)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LeonMeier See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236903/4427 for applying bold if `\boldmath` is in force.